# Why do I get two windows when using wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I wrote a hello world wxpython application but I notice when I run it I get two windows rendering.  See the screenshot with the window and the code.  Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: Chang `None` to app in `wx.Frame`

Comment: Doesn't run if I do that

Comment: If you expand the inner window, does it contain the word 'True'? If so, the inner window is just an odd variation of the fact that you have redirected sys.stdout and sys.stderr, with `wx.App(redirect=True)` You don't mention which version you are running or the OS.

Comment: This can't be all your code. I tried typing it in exactly as shown except that I added the `import wx` line that you are not showing and it only shows one Frame. wxPython 4.0.1, Python 3.5 on Xubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

```
#A code to open three window
# Imports the wx package
import wx

# Creates an application object
app = wx.App()

# Creates a Frame
top = wx.Frame(None, title="Hello World", size=(300, 200))

# You can add this line if you want to add more controls to the frame

top1 = wx.Frame(None, title="Bonjour le monde", size=(300, 200))
top2 = wx.Frame(None, title ="Hallo Welt", size=(400, 200))
top.Show(True)
top1.Show(True)
top2.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please add some code explanation to your code.